# Flutter wrap soft keyboard by any widget such as Container

Tags: flutter

If you have `whatsApp` application you know when we click on `attachment` when soft keyboard is shows, `whatsApp` can wrap soft keyboard by animation container

when keyboard is shows and when we click on `attachment` button:

[image]

is it possible to implementing this feature in `flutter`?

Comment: could you plz provide a video? not quite sure what do you mean (i do not use whatsapp)

Comment: @ch271828n i updated question with inserting a simple video of what i want to implement

Comment: does my solution work?

Comment: Hello may i know if you already solve this? I need this feature too

Comment: @anas i can't yet

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, what about trying this: pub.dev/packages/keyboard_overlay Do not use that package directly, since that package shows a customly drawn keyboard. But do use its idea - it reveals that, we can draw anything above the keyboard.

Secondly, another methodology is, draw something above everything in the android system. Please refer to [how to draw over other apps in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62241840/how-to-draw-over-other-apps-in-flutter) and the package https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/system_alert_window . If you can draw above everything, definitely you can draw above the keyboard, therefore creating the animation effect.

Comment: i'm trying to make a simple code with your links,i haven't successfully yet